# Filegrowth recommendations for Azure Managed Instance

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

On Azure SQL Managed Instances, im seeing new database getting 16MB filesize growth on database and logfiles (i changed log to 128MB). I haven't been able to find online docs from MS on recommendation here. 16MB is smaller then what i would normally run with,but since i'm new to Azure MI i not sure if i should make changes here.

```
SELECT [type_desc], [name], [growth], [growth] * 8 / 1024 AS GrowthInMB FROM sys.database_files

type_desc   name     growth GrowthInMB
ROWS        data_0  2048    16
LOG         log     16384   128
ROWS        data_1  2048    16
ROWS        data_2  2048    16
ROWS        data_3  2048    16
FILESTREAM  XTP 0   0
```

Anyone with actual field experience willing to chip in?

Comment: I don't believe Autogrowth will change its functioning just because it is on Azure MI. The practice that 'pre-size your data and log file to keep auto growth as less as possible' still applies. Yes 16 MB is smaller. I would go ahead with 500 GB for  data and 300 GB for log and then check auto growth events and change the value accordingly.

Comment: We are not on that level of capacity management ;) I'll need to let the applications do their thing. Was more wondering if it would make sense to bump filegrowth to 64 or 128MB chunks

Comment: I believe yes, 128 MB makes much more sense than 64. But I believe 128 MB would still be less.